# Display scroll in modal

Tags: css, ionic-framework, angular-bootstrap

I have app using angular-bootstrap and also ionicFramework.
Problem is in angular-bootstrap $modal element. I want it has vertical scrollbar, but in ionic.css there are style:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}
```

and because of this there is no scrollbar in modal.
I tried solve this problem in many ways, but now I am confused.

Comment: Why not change that line from `display:none` to something else?

Comment: @alex sometimes coders prefer to not alter the base css of a framework, so they write css after to overwrite framework css

Comment: @GraceLee Yeah, I generally do the same thing, but my question is still valid.

Comment: @GraceLee it is not I who downvoted your answer.

Comment: Why not use `ion-scroll` inside your modal?

Comment: @alex I want to know if there is another solution to solve my problem.

Comment: You are welcome! Posted as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `ion-scroll` component inside your modal, instead. Example:

```
<ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" style="width:500px;height:500px">
  <!-- Put your content here -->
</ion-scroll>
```

Reference: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/

Answer (score 11):

put your modal html component inside of ion-content

Comment: This is the correct answer, the accepted option does work but is a hack